# AngularJS append options to dropdown dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rather strange problem which I am unable to figure out. I am trying to append options to  dynamically but somehow it doesn't seem to work or I am missing something. Thanks in advance.[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HHTQiNSJQoUlPAYOV9IW?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not obvious. You **have** to have ng-model on your select for it to work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tsm0FvzCpf1BuGDkBpEB

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="c.name for c in list"></select>
```

I forget this often.

Comment: thanks a lot man! Was breaking my head over this. Any idea why it requires a ng-model ? Just interested to know. Nevertheless thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I don't know why it is required, but I can say this has stung me many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pocWRU6oIfHSLJQgFtSp?p=preview